# C "undefined reference" causing build fail on multi-source project

Tags: c, build, linker, codeblocks

I'm trying to build and run an executable from the source files below, but I keep getting the following messages upon build after a hassle-free compile:

```
undefined reference to 'lessThanFunction'
undefined reference to 'moreThanFunction'
```

I can't really understand how my functions aren't adequately defined.  I've been told it's a linker error, but the same code in a new project folder and files produces the same error.  I think I need to edit the .cbp file to recognize the .o file but I'm not really sure how.

***main.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main()
{
    /* variable declarations */
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    /* main function */
    printf("Enter two integer values, separated by a single space.  If the sum of the two values = 100 or more, the program will return HELLO.\n  If the sum of the two values = less than 100, the program will return GOODBYE.");
    scanf("%i %i", &x, &y);

    z = x + y;

    if(z > 100)
    {
        moreThanFunction(x, y, z);
    }

    if(z <= 100)
    {
        lessThanFunction(x, y, z);
    }
return 0;
}
```

***functions.h***

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

/* function declarations */
void moreThanFunction(int x, int y, int z);
void lessThanFunction(int x, int y, int z);

#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

***functions.c***

```
#include "functions.h"

/* function definitions */
void moreThanFunction(int x, int y, int z)
{
    printf("%i + %i = %i    Hello, world!", x, y, z);
}

void lessThanFunction(int x, int y, int z)
{
    printf("%i + %i = %i    Goodbye, world.", x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: You should mention that you're using Code Blocks. On a command line you would just compile both files with a single command, but with Code Blocks, I dunno.

Comment: Without knowing your OS and compiler, help will be limited (provide those for more). At first glance it seems simply that you need to build the two CPP files into a single output, so are you building at the command line? If so, show us the command line (which implies what OS you're using and which compiler).

Comment: OS is Win7, compiler is GNU GCC.  To build I set the focus in Code::Blocks to main.c, then, I go Build > Compile current file, then Build and Run.

@JVene When there's nothing but function definitions in the functions.h file, it works just fine.  The problem somehow occurs when I put the definitions in  the functions.c file and attempt to link them with the functions.h file.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from @KeithThompson in the previous invocation of this question? *"If you're using gcc, then `gcc functions.c main.c -o main` should give you an executable."*

Comment: Are both CPP files added to the project in Code::Blocks? (IDK how Code::Blocks works specifically, but in most IDEs, you have to add the file to the project so the IDE recognizes it as a source file)

Comment: @WeatherVane I just get 'gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Does no one use Code::Blocks?  It seems like it should be relatively straightforward to click the buttons that say compile and build and have them either work or point to problems you can actually see.

Comment: @ immibis Yes, they are inside the respective source and header folders in the project.

Comment: Nathaniel, you've hit the problem. When the definitions are in the header, the compiler sees that, builds it, all is fine. When you put them in the second .cpp file, they're not being compiled because your project in codeblocks is not configured correctly. The IDE keeps track of all the files in your project so as to issue the command to the compiler to include all the files in the build. Compile file command compiles only 1 file. Build command compiles all configured files and produces the output target. Did you in fact create a new project to start? Use Project/AddFiles

Comment: @JVene Created a new project and added my files to it.  Built and executed with no problems.  Thank you!